# Predual of a Finite von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, conditional-expectation, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $N$ be a finite von Neumann algebra with a fixed faithful normal trace $\tau$. Let $L^1(N)$ be the completion of $N$ with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ defined by $\|x\|_1=\tau (|x|)=\sup\{|\tau(xy)|:\|y\|\leq 1,\,y\in N\}$.

**Problem:** Prove that the Banach space dual of $L^1(N)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $N$.

I got stuck with this while reading [Section $3.6$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1etQjGJDNKIo2GcK_md6Cm3lS5qQYkIaB/view?usp=sharing) from the book 'Finite von Neumann algebras and masas' by Sinclair and Smith. They says that it follows from a standard duality argument. But I did not get their argument. More specifically, how do I show that for any bounded linear functional $\Phi:L^1(N)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, there exists a unique $x\in N$ such that $\Phi(y)=\tau(xy)$ for each $y\in N$? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(H_\tau,\pi_\tau,\Omega_\tau)$ be the cyclic GNS representation associated with $\tau$. For $x,y\in N$ we have
$$
|\Phi(yx^\ast)|\leq \|\Phi\|\tau(|yx^\ast|)\leq \|\Phi\|\tau(|x|^2)^{1/2}\tau(|y|^2)^{1/2}.
$$
Hence there exists a unique bounded sesquilinear form $b$ on $H_\tau$ such that $b(\pi_\tau(x)\Omega_\tau,\pi_\tau(y)\Omega_\tau)=\Phi(yx^\ast)$. By the Riesz representation theorem there exists a unique $a\in B(H_\tau)$ such that $\Phi(yx^\ast)=\langle \pi_\tau(x)\Omega_\tau,a\pi_\tau(y)\Omega_\tau\rangle$.

It remains to show that $a\in \pi_\tau(N)$. For that purpose recall that $\pi_\tau(N)'=\{\pi_\tau'(z)\mid z\in N\}$, where $\pi_\tau'(z)$ acts on $H_\tau$ by $\pi_\tau'(z)\pi_\tau(x)\Omega_\tau=\pi_\tau(xz)\Omega_\tau$. We have
\begin{align*}
\langle \pi_\tau(x)\Omega_\tau,a\pi_\tau'(z)\pi_\tau(y)\Omega_\tau\rangle&=\langle\pi_\tau(x)\Omega_\tau,a\pi_\tau(yz)\Omega_\tau\rangle\\
&=\Phi(yzx^\ast)\\
&=\Phi(y(xz^\ast)^\ast)\\
&=\langle \pi_\tau(xz^\ast)\Omega_\tau,a\pi_\tau(y)\Omega_\tau\rangle\\
&=\langle\pi_\tau(x)\Omega_\tau,\pi_\tau'(z)a\pi_\tau(y)\Omega_\tau\rangle
\end{align*}
for all $x,y,z\in N$. Thus $a\pi_\tau'(z)=\pi_\tau'(z)a$ for all $z\in N$, that is, $a\in \pi_\tau(N)''=\pi_\tau(N)$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I didn't compute the norm of $\Phi$ in your example, but I don't see what would go wrong. The first part of the inequality is $|\Phi(a)|\leq \|\Phi\| \|a\|_1$ and the second is Hölder's inequality. Also, $\Phi$ is defined on $L^1(N)$, so normality is not a meaningful condition. Is it possible that you computed the norm of $\Phi$ as a linear functional on $N$ instead?

Comment: Yes indeed. My bad.